# Spring Boot chaosmonkey

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I am trying to use chaos monkey with spring boot but getting the following error. Has anyone used it with spring cloud and Hystrix to test the fallback? Not able to start the server.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'chaosMonkeyRequestScope': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

I am using the following version :

```
springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'
springCloudVersion= "Greenwich.SR3"
"de.codecentric:chaos-monkey-spring-boot:2.1.0"
```

Comment: I've used 2.0.x here https://github.com/spencergibb/spring-cloud-kubernetes-demo/blob/spring-cloud-kubernetes/pom.xml#L31

Comment: Hi , Could you please have a look at mine what's wrong ?
https://github.com/chandresh87/MicroServices/blob/master/personMicroService/build.gradle

Comment: No idea what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I found, spring starter web dependency was missing somehow and everything was working fine except chaos money.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/codecentric/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/issues/118) in chaosmonkey in combination with spring cloud in latest chaos monkey release 2.1

Upgrade to [Chaos Monkey 2.1.1](https://github.com/codecentric/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/releases/tag/2.1.1) should fix your problem :)

For gradle:

```
compile 'de.codecentric:chaos-monkey-spring-boot:2.1.1'
```

For maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
  <artifactId>chaos-monkey-spring-boot</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```